# JavaScript code is returning all images, not just those defined for the current user

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

The below is a JavaScript parse.com code block. Its purpose is to return a list of images for the current user that is logged into the app. At the moment the code is returning all images, not just those of the current user.

I'm not sure what I've missed, unless I need to use the current user variable in the code block too?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("xxxxx", "xxxxx");

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();  
var myGlobalBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
if (currentUser) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(myGlobalBadges);
    query.exists("BadgeName");
     query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];
          imageURLs.push(object.get('BadgeName'));
        }
     // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
            $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");                 
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
       } else {


         // show the signup or login page
}   
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just managed to resolve this myself using the following code.

The following line changed from

```
query.exists("BadgeName");
```

to

```
 query.equalTo("username", currentUser);
```

---

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();  
var myGlobalBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");

    var query = new Parse.Query(myGlobalBadges);
    query.equalTo("username", currentUser);
     query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];
          imageURLs.push(object.get('BadgeName'));
        }
     // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++){
            $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");                 
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
         // show the signup or login page

 </script>
```